# mysql weight based query possible?

Tags: mysql

Suppose my table is is like.

```
 id   Name
  1  john 
  2  John Walker Terry
  3  John Terry
  4  Terry
```

Is it possible, in mysql, to search through name order by most number of sub string matches. If we search `John Terry` result order should be

```
John Terry
John Walker Terry
john
Terry
```

Comment: Are you trying to order the results by how good the match is? Use full-text searching.

Answer (score 1):

You could get those results with the following. But this will return anyone with John or Terry in their name so you might want to add some kind of ranking based on the match.

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE Name LIKE '%John%' OR Name LIKE '%Terry%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE NAME LIKE '%John%Terry%'
```

This query will search in forward direction only not in back.
You will get the following result

John Terry
John Walker Terry

but all results you are expecting is not possible with sql query.